# Matplotlib figure looks different when saved, compared to rendered in jupyter notebook

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

I am using seaborn style darkgrid. When I render the figure in jupyter it looks great. But when I save it with `savefig(figure.jpeg, dpi=300)`. The colors of the grid are bad. Funny, when I upload the figure here, it looks good again. What is going on? And when I drop it in Chrome it looks bad. Is this a transparency issue? It is mainly the darker area in the background that is affected.

```
%pylab inline
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_style('darkgrid')
plot(something)
```

I would like to save the figure as it is displayed in the jupyter notebook so I can use it in other applications. What does the browser, what other image viewers don't have?

I tried formats `jpeg` and `png`. And saved the figure with `transparency=True` and `transparency=False`.

[image]

Comment: I tried Firefox to look at this post and there the image looks bad. But the image should be saved as it is seen in Chrome.

Comment: Ok, maybe a screenshot would be helpful, as it's not clear what "bad" means, and probably not everyone is seeing the same thing, or consider is as "bad".

Comment: I see. I have a Chrome plugin named Deluminate. I is supposed to not change figures. Though when the option 'Enable low contrast' is activated the figure looks awesome. So, it is a browser issue.

Comment: So the aim here is to create a figure and save it such that it looks the same as when viewed with this plug-in? Then again, one would need to know how it looks with this plug-in, which isn't obvious, especially not for people who do not even have chrome, or do not want to install some plug-in for the purpose of understanding the question.

Comment: No. The aim is to understand why my image looks different in jupyter vs viewed through and image viewer. But I can mark the question for deletion if that is more appropriate. I guess the problem is more general than for this specific plugin.

Comment: One would need to know *how* it looks in both cases.

Comment: Unfortunately, you really have to install the plugin and give it a try. Screenshots don't work.

Comment: Maybe I can add a photo.